# In SQL Server, is there a way when using GROUPING SETS to remove duplicates while aggregating, without huge cardinality expansion?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

A simplified (and kind of silly) example will make what I'm asking a bit clearer. Bob/Tim are expected to be unique identifiers herein.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #People

CREATE TABLE #People 
(
    Person varchar(10), 
    City varchar(20), 
    Department varchar(1), 
    PersonAge int
);

INSERT INTO #People VALUES ('Bob', 'New York', 'A', 40),
                           ('Tim', 'New York', 'A', 30),
                           ('Tim', 'New York', 'B', 30)

;WITH InitialGrouping AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Person,
        City,
        Department,
        MAX(PersonAge) PersonAge,
        COUNT(*) NumRows
    FROM
        #People
    GROUP BY 
        Person, City, Department
) --SELECT * FROM InitialGrouping
SELECT 
    City,
    Department,
    AVG(PersonAge) AveragePersonAge,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Person) PersonCount
FROM
    InitialGrouping
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS (City, Department, (City, Department))
ORDER BY 
    City, Department

;WITH InitialGrouping AS 
(
    SELECT 
        GROUPING_ID(Person,City,Department) GROUPID,
        Person,
        City,
        Department,
        MAX(PersonAge) PersonAge,
        COUNT(*) NumRows
    FROM
        #People
    GROUP BY  
        Person, GROUPING SETS (City, Department, (City, Department))
) --SELECT * FROM InitialGrouping
SELECT 
    City,
    Department,
    AVG(PersonAge) AveragePersonAge,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Person) PersonCount
FROM 
    InitialGrouping
GROUP BY 
    GROUPID, City, Department
ORDER BY 
    City, Department
```

These two examples are not functionally equivalent. If you look at the rollup row for New York, you will see that the average age is wrong for the first one (33) and right for the second (35). The second is functionally correct, however, for more complex examples with lots of grouping sets, it can absolutely explode cardinality out in the concatenation step of the query plan, which causes performance to be unacceptable. In this simple example, you can see that the first query keeps things at 5 rows while the second expands to 8 rows. In more complex cases with lots of grouping sets, I've seen cardinality expand many many times across millions of rows.

Is there a way to solve this that can keep things from expanding past the target granularity of the final output?

There's a solution proposed in the comments below which does work. It may be the best option. It looks like this (I added an additional group):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #People

CREATE TABLE #People 
(
    Person varchar(10), 
    City varchar(20), 
    Department varchar(1), 
    Badge int,
    PersonAge int
);

INSERT INTO #People VALUES ('Bob', 'New York', 'A', 1, 40),
                           ('Tim', 'New York', 'A', 1, 30),
                           ('Tim', 'New York', 'B', 2, 30),
                           ('Tom', 'New York', 'B', 1, 30),
                           ('Jim', 'Paris', 'A', 2, 50)


;WITH InitialGrouping AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Person,
        City,
        Department,
        Badge,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person ORDER BY Person) OverallRowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, City, Department, Badge ORDER BY Person) CityDepartmentBadgeRowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, City, Department ORDER BY Person) CityDepartmentRowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, City, Badge ORDER BY Person) CityBadgeRowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, Badge, Department ORDER BY Person) DepartmentBadgeRowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, City ORDER BY Person) CityRowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, Department ORDER BY Person) DepartmentRowNum,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Person, Badge ORDER BY Person) BadgeRowNum,
        MAX(PersonAge) PersonAge
    FROM
        #People
    GROUP BY 
        Person, City, Department, Badge
) --SELECT * FROM InitialGrouping


SELECT 
    GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge),
    City,
    Department,
    Badge,
    CASE WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 7 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN OverallRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 6 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN BadgeRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 5 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN DepartmentRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 4 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN DepartmentBadgeRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 3 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN CityRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 2 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN CityBadgeRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 1 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN CityDepartmentRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         WHEN GROUPING_ID(City,Department,Badge) = 0 THEN AVG(CASE WHEN CityDepartmentBadgeRowNum = 1 THEN PersonAge ELSE NULL END)
         END AS AveragePersonAge,
    COUNT(DISTINCT Person) PersonCount
FROM
    InitialGrouping
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS (City, Department, Badge, (City, Department), (City,Badge), (Department,Badge), (City,Department,Badge),())
ORDER BY 
    City, Department
```

Comment: @marc_s is there a specific SQL format on SO I should be aware of?

Comment: If you “de-duplicate” the rows per grouping set using row_number() over(partition by grouping set,Person) and agreggate case when grouping_id() then avg(case when groupingrn=1 then Age) the plan is the same as the first/incorrect example with the addition of the sequences calculations..

Comment: Do you actually need grouping sets by `City` and by `Department` and by `City, Department`?

Comment: As I mentioned, the idea here is that we would want a solution that can expand to a larger number of grouping columns with a variety of sets. So yes, there would be examples where you need City, Department, (City, Department), and you could imagine several other grouping columns and arbitrary sets of them that you may want to group by. @lptr's solution does work although has the downside of becoming unruly as the number of sets increases because you need a different column for each grouping and then a large case statement. Still, might be the best available option which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0):

I use first way but change Method type order aggregate and use window function

```
 select  

    City,
    Department,
    max(PersonAge) AveragePersonAge,
    max( Person) PersonCount 

from (

    select 
             City
            ,Department
            ,AVG(PersonAge) over(partition by City )  as PersonAge
            ,

    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Person ASC) +
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Person DESC) - 1 AS Person     

     from #People
)a
GROUP BY 
    GROUPING SETS (Department,City,(Department,City) )
ORDER BY 
    City, Department
```

Comment: Hm, that works for my simplified example. However, as I mentioned my goal is to expand to a larger number of groups, and it doesn't carry across unless I'm missing a way to make that work. Since I can't add code here: If you for example add a third column, call it [Group], and then add a third person, call him Tom and make him 30 years old. Add Tom to a different group than Bob and Tim, but otherwise put him in 'New York', 'A'. If you look at the rollup for 'A', you'll see an incorrect value of 35 for average age and an incorrect count of 2 for person count.

Comment: Or even better, without adding a group: Add that line for Tom like this: ('Tom', 'New York', 'B', 30), then look at the rollup row for New York. So, this won't even work for the simplified example.

Comment: i think you said first code is better code but result is not true 
i solve your problem 
now your first code is true with my correction
i can't understand your problem
can you say me your problem and show my Final result and explain me@JS

Comment: The goal is that in each grouping set, we should have a correct count of distinct people in that grouping set, and the average age of those distinct people. You didn't solve that unfortunately - you solved it for the exact three example rows. The solution should be able to generalize to any set of data and yours does not. As I mentioned, if we were to add a fourth row ('Tom', 'New York', 'B', 30) your code no longer works for the New York rollup, which should now have 3 distinct people and an average age of 33.

Comment: I edited this code  "distinct people and average age"

you use City,Department in group by 
my code use City,Department for get avg similar your code if you remove "Department" of this code " AVG(PersonAge) over(partition by City ) as PersonAge" that avg is 130%4= 32@JS

Comment: That then breaks other rows. One could try the inelegant approach of creating a different column for each grouping we care about (e.g., CityDepartmentPersonAge, CityPersonAge, etc), then using GROUPING_ID and a CASE statement to distinguish between them. This unfortunately also has a very bad query plan.

Comment: @JS You should add all edge cases to your question and explain what results you want and by what logic, as it's a bit unclear at the moment